# SPFx Application customizer and hiding list in Modern Site

Tags: spfx-extensions, modern-team-site

Is there a way to Hide List view & List settings page for certain user. Idea is make the list inaccessible to through UI and programmatic access and user will only access data via Power App. Below is what I have explored so far
1. Hide from browser property in Designer- Not useful as user with direct URL can still access the list
2. Permissions cant be restricted as I still want to give end user create item permission

Is there a way to make list completely inaccessible through browser, I was thinking Application Customizer  - Extension but wanted to confirm if its the smartest available way to tackle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you still want the user to have permissions to access the list items it will be hard to hide it completely. You can obfuscate it in ways like you have mentioned, but I do not feel this will be a good solution. The users can still find the list through URL manipulation, SharePoint API, Search etc.

What are you going to use this data for? Is it only to be available and used in the Power App? In that case I would take a look at [Common Data Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/data-platform-intro) instead of a SharePoint list to store the data.

From the link:

> Common Data Service has a rich security model to protect the data
>   integrity and privacy of users while promoting efficient data access
>   and collaboration. You can combine business units, role-based
>   security, record-based security, and field-based security to define
>   the overall access to information that users have in a Common Data
>   Service environment.